# opengl not drawing anything

Tags: c++, opengl

Just trying to draw a point using glut and glew for opengl version 4.3

my code

```
void Renderer(void)
{ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glPointSize(100);
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3d(10, 10, 0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

is not rendering anything, can someone tell me what did i miss? here is full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOS };

#define WIDTH 1024
#define HEIGHT 768
#define REFRESH_DELAY     10 //ms

//general
long frameCount = 0;

// mouse controls
int mouse_old_x, mouse_old_y;
int mouse_buttons = 0;
float rotate_x = 0.0, rotate_y = 0.0;
float translate_z = -3.0;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Prototypes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void motion(int x, int y);

void timerEvent(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(REFRESH_DELAY, timerEvent, frameCount++);
}

void init (void)
{
    // default initialization
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat)WIDTH / (GLfloat)HEIGHT, 1, 10000.0);
}

void Renderer(void)
{ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glPointSize(100);
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3d(10, 10, 0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow("The Abyss");
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    glutTimerFunc(REFRESH_DELAY, timerEvent, frameCount);

    if (glewInit()) //i guess this is true on failure
    {
        cerr << "Error initializing glew, Program aborted." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    //Init First
    init();

    //Init callback for Rendering
    glutDisplayFunc(Renderer);

    //Main Loop
    glutMainLoop();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//!Mouse and keyboard functionality
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int /*x*/, int /*y*/)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case (27) :
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouse_buttons |= 1<<button;
    }
    else if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        mouse_buttons = 0;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    float dx, dy;
    dx = (float)(x - mouse_old_x);
    dy = (float)(y - mouse_old_y);

    if (mouse_buttons & 1)
    {
        rotate_x += dy * 0.2f;
        rotate_y += dx * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (mouse_buttons & 4)
    {
        translate_z += dy * 0.01f;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}
```

Comment: "for opengl version 4.3" well if it's for version 4.3 then why are you using all those functions which was deprecated from version 3.1 ?

Comment: Aren't you drawing in normalized coordinates? What happens if you draw at (0.5, 0.5, 0.0)?

Comment: @user1118321: (0.5, 0.5, 0.0) is the exact center of the screen in OpenGL NDC, where -1.0 is the nearplane and 1.0 is the farplane. If he were drawing in NDC, this would be the center of the screen; his perspective projection matrix rules out drawing in NDC, however.

Answer (score 3):

```
glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

You have requested a Core context.  You need to:

1. Specify a vertex and fragment shader.  There are no freebies in Core.
2. Stop using deprecated functionality like `glBegin()` and `glMatrixMode()`.
3. Start using VBOs to submit your geometry.
4. Start using `glDrawArrays()` and friends to draw your geometry.

Comment: To elaborate - all listed functionality is completely unavailable in core profile with specified version and will result in GL error. Either that, or use compatibility profile.